# WatchOS 3 and iOS 10 - Exercise times

Tags: apple-watch, health.app

So I'm running iOS 10 and Watch OS 3.  I turned on my workout on my apple watch and went for a walk for 28 min.  When I was done, I checked the workout and it says 28 min.  If I go into my 'Activity' on the watch or my iPhone, it says my exercise for the day was only 11 min... But I can click on the workout and see it was 28 min.  Any ideas?

[image: Activity Status]

[image: Workout on Watch OS]

Answer (score 1):

WATCH determines a certain activity threshold beyond which it will consider an activity to be exercise. This threshold is specific to each individual, and takes into account your heart rate throughout the day vs. during an activity, your previous activities, etc.

Your average heart rate for that walk seems high enough to be considered exercise, although once again it is difficult to tell the exact threshold WATCH is using for your specifically. With that in mind, if we assume that the average heart rate is high enough, then that leaves us with the pace.

According to Apple, an activity needs to be at the level of a brisk walk or faster for it to grant credit. You may try checking periods where you might have walked faster or slower, and seeing if you can correlate those to the bars on the Exercise graph.

I hope this helps. I’m sorry if it can sound demoralizing to have an electronic device “judging” your activity level, but don’t get discouraged!